# Convert string to resource while data binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone

I’m developing a Windows phone 7.5 – 8.0 app.
Very often, I need to choose some resource from a resource dictionary based on the value that comes from data binding.

First I did this:

```
public class EventValueConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public delegate object ConvertEventHandler( EventValueConverter sender, object value );

    object IValueConverter.Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        var eh = this.Convert;
        if( null == eh )
        {
            Logger.warning( "EventValueConverter.Convert is not set - returning null." );
            return null;
        }
        return eh( this, value );
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public event ConvertEventHandler Convert;
}
```

Added the converter to the page resources, and implemented the event in the page code behind:

```
public object myConverter_Convert( EventValueConverter converter, object val )
{
    return this.Resources[ val.ToString() ];
}
```

It works great. The problem is Blend don’t like that my converter, saying “Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component”. It happens when opening the page, and the message is shown in place of my page, thus making Blend unusable for that page.

However, I like Blend. That's why I’ve created another converter for the same tasks:

```
public class PageResourceConverter: IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        if( null == value )
            return null;

        string name = value.ToString();
        if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( name ) )
            return null;

        object res = null;
        var page = getCurrentPage();
        if( null == page )
            return null;
        res = page.Resources[ name ];

        if( null == res )
        {
            Logger.warning( "Resource {0} was not found", name );
            return null;
        }
        return res;
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    internal static PhoneApplicationPage getCurrentPage()
    {
        if( Global.inFormDesigner ) return null;
        return ( (PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual ).Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
    }
}
```

This too works OK. And it doesn’t crash Blend. However, it doesn’t work in design mode, because the Application.Current.RootVisual is null. How to make it work in design mode?

Or, what’s the correct way to return a resource from a converter? I don’t want to create a separate converter for every type of enumeration + every kind of string ID I need to resolve to a style or brush or some other resource.

Comment: Thanks - just what I needed! I could access the application resources, but couldn't figure out how to access the page resources. Much appreciated!